# Incorrect SUM in HANA Calculation Graphical View

Tags: hana

I am trying to do a Sum of quantity for products, using HANA Calculation Graphical View.

| MATNR | MENGE |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 1 |
| AAA | 2 |
| AAA | 2 |
| BBB | 2 |
| BBB | 3 |

Using aggregation node, I choose MATNR as normal output and MENGE at Aggregated Output.

The result is, MATNR AAA always shows 3 which is not correct (BBB is 5, correct).

I tried set the source view to CUBE, change MATNR to attribute (and make it KEY field), also change MENGE to measure. Every suggestion I have read but no luck.

I understand that aggregation node auto groups the same value before Sum. How do I avoid it and get correct result for MATNR AAA?

Thank you

Comment: Please post the SQL command you use to query your view and also what HANA version/revision you're using.

Comment: @LarsBr. I didn't use SQL command, it is Graphical View. HANA studio Version: 2.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a note about this behavior of HANA https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1764658

Following the note, set a `Keep Flag` to distinguish more fields in the node before (under) aggregation node will solve the problem.